# How are atoms split into subatomic particles?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, subatomic

How are atoms split into subatomic particles such as neutrons, protons or electrons? And I mean in the practical sense, not just theoretically

Comment: Using the [Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collider)

Comment: @RedGiant that's not the only way of course, just ionize hydrogen which uses far less energy than colliders use and you've already split an atom into protons and electrons.

Comment: Or just dissolve salt in water.

Answer (score 2):

Atoms are broken apart by hitting them with tiny but very powerful bullets in the form of other particles like electrons, protons, neutrons, or with bursts of extremely energetic radiation.

Those bullet particles are fired from huge, complex guns called *particle accelerators*  that whip the particles up to tremendous energies before shooting them at their targets. The resulting impacts are sufficient to shatter the target atoms completely to pieces, and to very briefly create new particles which themselves quickly fly apart.

To guarantee that as much of the impact energy as possible is harnessed to accomplish this, it is common to accelerate both the bullets and their targets in opposite directions and then smash them into each other head-on in a special accelerator called a *collider*.

Gigantic sensors called *detectors* surround the scene of these collisions and catch the shattered fragments and measure their trajectories, electrical charges, and energy levels, allowing the physicists to identify the fragments and figure out exactly what took place during the collision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although how are the bullets made of subatomic particles created in the first place?

Comment: you start for example with hydrogen atoms, and electrically peel off the electrons with extremely high voltages. using opposite voltages, you then separate the electrons from the protons and focus them into beams, which you then inject into the head end of the accelerator. For neutrons, you shoot electrons or protons at an atom which has an excess of neutrons, which knocks some of them loose in a process called *spallation*.